# shell script using awk

Tags: shell, scripting, awk

Having troubles with `awk`. Basically what I'm trying to do is search for this particular string in the file. And then print the 3rd element of that line.

Here's what I did:

```
awk -F' / ' '$1=="$log"{print $3}' schedlist
```

For some reason that won't work but if I do this:

```
awk -F' / ' '$1=="20121213-20:58:53"{print $3}' schedlist
```

The code works. But I need to let the user input `log` name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options.  Use a variable ( either with `-v` or simply as an assignment, but you cannot name it "log", because that is an awk function):

```
awk -F' / ' '$1 == s {print $3}' s="$log" schedlist
```

quote your script differently:

```
awk -F' / ' '$1 == "'"$log"'" { print $3}' schedlist
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `-v` option to pass a shell variable into `awk`, like this:

```
awk -v tstamp="$log" -F' / ' '$1==tstamp{print $3}' schedlist
```

(Updated the variable name to `tstamp` (as mentioned in the comments), because `log` clashes with the awk built-in function `log`.)

Comment: Hmmm I've tried that and I get this error:awk: run time error: cannot command line assign to log
 type clash or keyword
 FILENAME="" FNR=0 NR=0

Comment: +1 for the correct answer but unlucky that you picked a variable name that clashes with a builtin function name "log"! Just change the variable name to tstamp or something: `awk -v tstamp="$log" -F' / ' '$1==tstamp{print $3}' schedlist`